# understanding the format of file and converting into byte c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, xml, web-services, byte

I am creating a web app where i am converting file from (docx, xlxs, images, pdf) to byte,

angularjs help me to convert the file but i don't know in which format the files has been converted

here is the output

> data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDfpNJsWgEAACAFAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooA

```
openxmlformats-
```

this line indicates that the data is in xml format but i want to convert the data from this format to byte array from webservice

how i need to do this thing?

Comment: It's possible that your bytes were encoded to base64. Pass whatever you got through a Bas64 decoder and see what happens (ie: do you get your hex values?)..

Answer (score 0):

To converting data to byte array you do not need to know the file type just convert it to byte array.

Converting to byte array means I want to see the source data of any file therefore this is not important the file type just convert it.

The suffix only help application easily determine the file type but not changed the binary data or affect to file data

### Function convert to byte array

```
byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Note that `obj` and any properties/fields within `obj` (and so-on for all of their properties/fields) will all need to be tagged with the [`Serializable` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to successfully be serialized with this.

### 2- Convert file directly to byte array

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

Comment: How i need to convert this into byte array??

Comment: @InformationHTI put your file in this function and convert it to binary array